# Set label title from mouseEntered in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mouseover, setstring

I have this code in my `NSButton` subclass:

```
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"ENTER");
    NSString *myString = @"foo";
    [myTextField setStringValue:myString];
}
-(IBAction)changeStringValue:(id)sender{
    NSString *myString = @"foo";
    [myTextField setStringValue:myString];
}
```

The IBAction works fine but the same method of `myTextField` called inside the `mouseEntered event` doesn't work. The event is working (except setString), in fact I can see the NSLog and if I insert `NSLog(@"%@", myTextField.stringValue);`, it says `null`.
Does anyone have a clue?

Edit: I noticed that the previous stringValue NSLog, if inserted in `-(void)awakeFromNib{...}`, occours 2 times even if there's only one button of `MyButton` class: one time it's correct and the other time it's `null`. I'm a little bit confused.

Edit2: i've inserted `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeStringValue:) withObject:myTextField waitUntilDone:YES];` inside the `mouseEnter:` event and `NSLog(@"Running");` inside the changeStringValue function: now hovering the button i call the function (i see the "running" log) but nothing happens. The function, as a Sent Action assigned to a button, is still working. I've also tried with `waitUntilDone:YES/NO` and `withObject:myTextField/self` but it's the same.

Comment: answers even disappear :D
If I bind the subclass `MyButton` into AppDelegate and insert `-(void)awakeFromNib{NSLog(@"awake: %@", myButton.myTextField.stringValue);}` in `AppDelegate.m`, it displays the right value too. Why is it `null` in mouseEntered?

Comment: SOLVED. I used NSNotificationCenter and it seems to be no alternative to it.